# why does the Shortcut assigned to the view roll command not work?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

Calling the "view roll" command with the shortcut does not work in Object mode and Edit mode, but it works, for example, in Draw mode.

How to make the shortcut work in all modes?

[image]

My shortcut set up in the settings ( 3D View -> 3D View ( Global ) )

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These custom shortcuts (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>) are already assigned to other operators in a few modes. If you want them to do the new function, you need to remove the old function first.

1. Open the preferences (*Edit > Preferences*).
2. Click *Keymap*.
3. Switch to *Key-Binding* search.
4. Type *Shift 1* in the search box.
5. Remove the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> bindings other than the one you added by pressing the *x* button.

Repeat the steps for the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> binding.

[image: Bindings]

As you can see in the screenshot, the shortcuts are not used in *Texture Paint* mode which allows your custom shortcuts to work as expected.

Comment: I removed all "Shift + 1" Shortcuts except "View Roll", but on pressing Shortcut the command still fails. Am I missing something?

[Image List](https://ibb.co/W5BfV88) of all Shortcuts when searching by "Shift + 1"

Comment: I carried out the steps I listed above and added the shortcuts the same way you did, and they work for me. Do you have *Emulate Numpad* enabled? You can find it in the preferences under *Input > Keyboard*. If it's enabled, disable it, and check if that makes the shortcuts work as intended.

Comment: I see what the problem is. When I press the combination "Shift + 1", for example, Blender for some reason executes the Hide Collection command, for which the hotkey "1" is set. Strange, why is that? 

Anyway, I just deactivated hotkeys "1" and "2" that activate the Hide Collection command and everything worked fine